# Read data from a CSV into a nested array in Java

Tags: java, csv, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to turn a .csv file in the following form (with an arbitrary number of columns):

```
a,b,c
d,e,f
g,h,i
```

into an int[][] like so:

```
int[][] a = {{a,b,c},{d,e,f},{g,h,i}}
```

in Java. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: How many rows would be there in the CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to give the whole answer (there are parts you should be able to look up yourself), but:

1) Use `split()` to split up an input line into fields.  The result is a `String[]`.

2) The most straightforward way to convert each `String` to an `int` is by using streams.  If `fields` is the `String[]`, then you can use:

```
 int[] ints = Arrays.stream(fields).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

This assumes there aren't any parse errors.  If you want to handle invalid input gracefully, you may need to use a loop instead of a stream.

To break this down: `Arrays.stream` creates a "stream" that gives you all the `Strings` in the array.  `mapToInt` turns the stream into an `IntStream` (a stream of `int`; note that there are special stream types when the elements have a primitive type like `int`).  It does this by applying a method, `Integer.parseInt`, that takes a `String` parameter and returns an `int`.  `toArray` on an `IntStream` then builds an `int[]` from the stream.

3) Use an `ArrayList<int[]>` to hold an array of all lines, since you don't know beforehand how many lines there will be.  If you want an `int[][]`, you can convert the `ArrayList` to an array later.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use one of the many CSV-parsers which you can find on the internet. For example https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

If you want to do it manually, you can read your file line by line and use a StringTokenizer to Split each line into tokens which you can then parse into the appropriate Java type.